# Write expressions that use bitwise operators, equality checks, and Boolean operators to do the following in O(1) time

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitmask

• Right propagate the rightmost set bit in x, e.g., turns (01010000) to (01011111).

I am stuck on this one. I can mask out the right-most bit with `x &= ~(x-1)` how can I set the bits after it as the problem states?

My attempt:

```
int problemOne(int n)
{
    int k = n;
    k &= ~(n-1);
    n |= k;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: `(n ? n|(n-1) : 0)`, but you're not allowed to use arithmetic operators like -

Answer (score 3):

You are actually closer than you think, you have all of the pieces you need already. `n-1` will set all bits to the right of the rightmost set bit, just because of how binary addition/subtraction works. You don't need to negate this, since you now have the desired bits set. You actually just need to take this OR the original input to combine the bits you are newly setting with the existing set bits in `n`. In other words, this can be a one-liner: `return (n | (n-1))`.

Another quick tip, it can sometimes be useful to work out little logic questions in a Python REPL to avoid the time-consuming cycle of troubleshooting your logic in a lower-level language like C. For example, in a Python 3 shell it took me just a few moments to confirm that this worked how I thought it did: `f'{((x-1) | x):b}'` prints the correct result for your sample input.

Comment: Using `n-1` supposes that the operator list given in the question is non-exclusive.  Myself, I initially read it as an exclusive list of operators that may be used, but that might not be how the OP meant it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger OP already used `n-1` in their code, so that shouldn't be a problem.